# ElementTree Parsing with Dynamic Variables Works in Spyder but not in PyCharm

Tags: python, pycharm, spyder, elementtree

I recently switched from Spyder to PyCharm, and a section of my code which parses an ElementTree with dynamic variables doesn't function in PyCharm.

In my GUI, default equipment settings for different research study protocols are read from an existing XML file. The code imports the XML file as an ElementTree, and iterates over it to populate a QComboBox with the study names. This part still works fine (all the study names appear in my combo box), so I know that ElementTree is imported properly and the XML file is being read.

```
import xml.etree.ElementTree as ET

def combofill(self):
    """Re-read xml file and re-populate drop-down menu"""
    self.tree = ET.parse('studydefaults.xml')
    self.root = self.tree.getroot()
    self.studyCombo.clear()
    self.studyCombo.addItem("None")
    for study in self.root.findall('study'):
        self.studyCombo.addItem(study.get('name'))
```

But, when the user selects a study from the ComboBox, the parameters associated with that study should be read from the ElementTree to fill other QLineEdits in the GUI. This uses dynamic variable names to search for the children of the currently selected study. This part works fine in Spyder, but with PyCharm the QLineEdits don't populate and I get errors:

```
def read_defaults(self):
    """Read and import default settings from XML file(s) to LineEdits."""
    if self.studyCombo.currentIndex() >= 1:           #item 1 = 'none'
        name = self.studyCombo.currentText()      #get name of current study

        #access parameters using elementtree xpaths to xml tags
        self.xrate_box.setText(self.root.find(".//*[@name='"+ name +"']/xrate").text)
        self.xduration_box.setText(self.root.find(".//*[@name='"+ name +"']/xduration").text)
        #etc for 7 other parameters/comboboxes
```

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "B:/Wilson/WinPython-64bit-2.7.10.3/sarah_development/V2-MasterClock/dwf_MainWindow.py", line 671, in read_defaults
    self.qrate_box.setText(str(self.root.findall(".//*[@name='"+ name +"']/qrate")))
  File "B:\Wilson\WinPython-64bit-2.7.10.3\python-2.7.10.amd64\lib\xml\etree\ElementTree.py", line 390, in findall
    return ElementPath.findall(self, path, namespaces)
  File "B:\Wilson\WinPython-64bit-2.7.10.3\python-2.7.10.amd64\lib\xml\etree\ElementPath.py", line 293, in findall
    return list(iterfind(elem, path, namespaces))
  File "B:\Wilson\WinPython-64bit-2.7.10.3\python-2.7.10.amd64\lib\xml\etree\ElementPath.py", line 263, in iterfind
    selector.append(ops[token[0]](next, token))
KeyError: PyQt4.QtCore.QString(u'.')
```

I have a hunch that this is a type error, so I have tried various ways of converting the element to a string in the setText commands, including:

```
self.xrate_box.setText(self.root.find(str(".//*[@name='"+ name +"']/xrate")))
```

and

```
self.xrate_box.setText(str(self.root.find(".//*[@name='"+ name +"']/xrate")))
```

These have given me the same errors as the ".text" approach.

Unfortunately due to some other issues & management decisions I need to stick with PyCharm and can't just revert to Spyder. Any suggestions on how to overcome this would be really appreciated!

Comment: My guess is that your Python environment for PyCharm and Spyder are different. Your error indicates you are using Python2.7 on PyCharm. Is this correct? You might also want to check if you're using the same python packages.

Comment: @GinoMempin, I am using the same python2.7 install/interpreter path for both Spyder and Python.

Comment: You mean in Spyder, you are also using WinPython-64bit-2.7.10.3? OK.. how about your Python packages? Though, `xml` should be a built-in package. I find it hard to believe that the behavior of the `xml` packages depends on the IDE.

Comment: The file path to ElementPath.py in the error above is in the folder of the original Spyder&python download/install; Spyder couldn't have been using a different xml package because that is (or at least should be) the only one on the computer! I agree that it hard to believe the behavior of the xml package depends on the IDE, but the evidence suggests thats what is happening.